# Keyboard obscures input text area

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I have a form that is displayed inside http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/. The issue is that when cursor is placed inside the final input (text area), the keyboard shows but the input doesn't scroll back into view and is obscured by the keyboard. The user has to scroll down.

I am using an android device.

The [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/) says

> Ionic will attempt to prevent the keyboard from obscuring inputs and focusable elements when it appears by scrolling them into view. In order for this to work, any focusable elements must be within a Scroll View or a directive such as Content that has a Scroll View.

If I wrapped the form with ion-content tag, the input box does scroll back into view but using  messes up with my layout and am looking for another solution.

Update:
How the manifest lookslike

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="myAwesomeApp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="me.apla.cordova.AppPreferencesActivity" />
    <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your Activity in AndroidMenifest

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cordova keyboard you can Use `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);` when the popup open and use `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` when it closes. 
this way the layout can handle overlapping keyboard in case of using popups.

Comment: Am not using  cordova keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest to the `Application` or to the `Activity`.

And check whether you set something like, `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(...)` in your Activity. If so, remove those lines.

Comment: Please take a look at the manifest in my question. That settings is already there.

Comment: yes. I had a look, and its set in only one Activity, not in Application. how do i know thats the Activity where the keyboard problem presents.

Comment: So should I add that setting each Activity tag? This file is generated and isn't manually put together. I think cordova generates this file for us. Is there some kind of hook in Ionic or Cordova where this setting can be set?